# cv::InputArray is not accepting cv::Matx31d. Why?

Tags: c++, opencv, distortion

I am trying to pass `cv::Matx31d` as an argument for `objectPoints`.

```
cv::fisheye::projectPoints(objectPoints, imgpoints, rvec, tvec, K, D);
```

But it is throwing following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (objectPoints.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3)) || objectPoints.type() == (((6) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3))) in projectPoints, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp, line 77
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:77: error: (-215) objectPoints.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3)) || objectPoints.type() == (((6) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3)) in function projectPoints
```

My C++ program is:

```
cv::Matx33d K(541.2152931632737, 0.0, 661.7479652584254,
              0.0, 541.0606969363056, 317.4524205037745,
              0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
cv::Vec4d D(-0.042166406281296365, -0.001223961942208027, -0.0017036710622692108, 0.00023929900459453295);
cv::Matx31d objectPoints(2, 2, 1);    // x, y, z coordinates
cv::Matx31d rvec(0, 0, 0);
cv::Matx31d tvec(0, 0, 0);
cv::Matx21 imgpoints;
cv::fisheye::projectPoints(objectPoints, imgpoints, rvec, tvec, K, D);
```

On the contrary, if I pass objectPoints & imgpoints as vector of `cv::Point`. It works.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> imgpoints;
std::vector<cv::Point3d> objectPoints;
objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(2, 2, 1));
```

**Can't I pass `cv::Matx31d objectPoints(2, 2, 1)`?**
I prefer `Matx` because I can initialize it with pointerToData.
e.g.

```
cv::Matx<double, 3, 100> objectPoints(pointer);
```

Comment: It [needs](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.1/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L77) `obcjectPoints` to have 3 channels. `InputArray` wrapping a `Matx` [determines the type](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L115) (which includes channel type as well) from the first template argument of the `Matx`. In this case it's `double`, so you don't meet the requirement for 3 channel input.

Comment: On the other hand, for `std::vector<cv::Point3d>`, it determines the type from `cv::Point3d`, which is treated as [having 3 channels](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L296).

Comment: ".... because I can initialize it with pointerToData" -- you can do that with `Mat3d` too. Just make it single column. Should behave just like the vector.

Comment: Can I pass Matx31d in `cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec, tvec, obj.new_K, cv::Matx41d(), imgpoints);` ?(https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c). Documentation says it can accept 3xN/Nx3 1-channel.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, Can you make an Mat3d example for lets say n 3D-points. Lets say the double pointer is pointing towards x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ..., xn, yn, zn.

Comment: You'd use [this constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#a276b9680948ebd82e3d8a7c1fa77af3c). Keep in mind that it doesn't copy the data, so the source array needs to exist for the entire lifetime of that `Mat_` instance. `n` rows, 1 column.

Comment: I tried with
    `double a[6]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    Mat3d temp2(2,1, &a[0]);`
It throws following error:
`mat.hpp:2162:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'double *' to 'const cv::Vec<double, 3>' for 3rd argument
mat.hpp:2176:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'double *' to 'cv::Vec<double, 3> *' for 3rd argument`